# How to receive data via Bluetooth on an Arduino 101?

Tags: bluetooth

The Arduino 101 came out recently, and it has built-in "Bluetooth Low Energy" capabilities. The tutorials and code examples that can be found for the 101 all seem to be about *transmitting* data, but I can't find anything about *receiving* data. I've tried to go through the source code of the CurieBle library to find some hints, but I feel a little overwhelmed/lost. Could someone point me to a code example which demonstrates how to do this?

Context: I was previously using an HC-05 module paired with an Arduino Nano in order to receive data. In this case it is quite easy to connect the HC-05 to the Nano's digital pins and receive data like so:

```
#define RxD 7 // This is the pin that the Bluetooth (BT_TX) 
              // will transmit to the Arduino (RxD)
#define TxD 8 // This is the pin that the Bluetooth (BT_RX) 
              // will receive from the Arduino (TxD)

SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD,TxD);

void setup() { 
  blueToothSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Allow Serial communication via USB cable to computer
  pinMode(RxD, INPUT);
  // Set up the Arduino to receive INPUT from the HC-05 on Digital Pin 7
  pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
  // Set up the Arduino to send OUTPUT to the HC-05 on Digital Pin 8
}

void loop() { 
  char recvChar;
  while(1) {
    if(blueToothSerial.available()) {
      recvChar = blueToothSerial.read();
      Serial.print("Read character: ");
      Serial.println(recvChar);
      // Print the character received to the Serial Monitor
    }
  }
}
```

Is there equivalent, and equally simple, code available, which would do the same thing via the BLE built into the Arduino 101?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Arduino Callback LED tutorial, you can use the dedicated library to access the BLE features of the board. All the Curie Libraries are covering the new Arduino/Genuino 101 embedded characteristics .
In your case you must incluse the CurieBLE.h and configure the bluetooth service with Read/Write access.

Have a look to [this page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Genuino101CurieBLECallbackLED) for a complete sample.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the 101 only supports Bluetooth LE stack and not the full Bluetooth stack including RFCOMM, virtual com port. This means there is no proper supported way, but it seems people are working on workarounds.

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=370123.0

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to using HC-05 with Intel 101.

I worked on the pin 0, 1, as the Serial1 class.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate.