# CurieBLE receive data without pairing

Tags: bluetooth, genuino, 101

I [read](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/how-to-receive-data-via-bluetooth-on-an-arduino-101) [exist](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=370123.0) [articles](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Genuino101CurieBLECallbackLED) about it, but still not understand how to do that.
I have a Genuino 101 and an EEG Headband (neuro interface). Need to get data from neuro device. With external HC-05 bluetooth module the code look like this:

```
 SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);
 bluetooth.begin(57600); 
 while (!bluetooth.available()) {}
 byteRead = bluetooth.read();
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?
Thanks!

Comment: what problem are you referring to?

Comment: The code above will only read one byte

Comment: @dandavis I want to get one byte using BLE without pairing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HC-05 module is not BLE (Bluetooth 4.0)! HC-05 implements SPP (Serial port profile) over Bluetooth Classic (Bluetooth 2.0). You will need a module with BLE capability and that is not over yet. BLE implements several (hundred) profiles for each task such as heartrate monitor, neuro monitor, time etc etc. Your BLE module must be condigured to receive a specific profile data.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

So without SPP and detail configurations for BLE I can't receive data from neuro?

Comment: Seems like not :(